# How to increase vector size with realloc and print all values?

Tags: c

I'm working on a task where I have to dynamically create a vector, of size 10. And, after creating, I must populate data in each index of this vector, and then immediately call a function that changes the value of the first position with the value of the last one, and so on. This is something I've achieved so far, but it makes no sense to do this without dynamic allocation

So, I need to increase the vector size to 20 and print all values again.
I'm having trouble with the relocation, I'm not sure if I really need such a function or if I could just relocate the size in the main function... And if I change the size to 20, how could I print the values again?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readVector(int* vector){
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
  }
}

void invertPosition(int* v, int n) {
    int j = 0;
    
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("Position[%d] = %d\n", j, v[i]);
        j++;
    }
}

int* reallocVector(int* v, int newSize){
  int* vet = (int*) realloc(v, sizeof(newSize));

  for(int i = 0; i<newSize; i++)
    vet[i] = i;
 
  return vet;
}

int main()
{
    // Create vector dinamically
    int *numbers = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

    printf("=> Enter vector numbers (10 values)\n");
    readVector(numbers);
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("=> Vector after modification\n");
    invertPosition(numbers, 10);
    
    reallocVector(numbers, 20);

    return 0;
}
```

If anyone can help me with this part of resizing the size to 20, I'll be grateful, because I'm not getting it

Comment: It's quite easy. Just send in the pointer to the memory you allocated before and get a new one back - and check that it worked.

Comment: `numbers = reallocVector(numbers, 20);`

Comment: You need to add error checking in `reallocVector`.  Both `malloc` and `realloc` can fail.

Comment: Why do you need to increase the size of the vector to invert it?

Comment: What's the point of using `realloc()` if you're just going to overwrite everything? Usually you use `realloc()` because you want to change the size but keep the old data.

Comment: In `reallocVector `, the second argument to `realloc`, namely `sizeof(newSize)` is certainly wrong. That's the size of an `int`. Period. the *value* of `newSize` is what you're really hunting, as in `newSize * sizeof *v`. And back in `main` you'd probably best be in the market for doing something with the result of `reallocVector` besides just letting it rot into ether. Like... maybe using it and later `free`ing it.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your task: you do _not_ need to reallocate to perform an inversion.  Don't get caught on side tasks